# Android : Call Recording error if existing recorder app engage in recording

Tags: android, call

```
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        fileName = FileHelper.getFilename(phoneNumber);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.start();
```

It works perfectly in my device .But when i have another recording application  it is unable to record the audio says "Another application is trying  to record".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. It's a singleton method.

Comment: o it's save my day